# using php template in symfony 2 instead of twig

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to display a symfony template using php..However, symfony is treating my php tags as "comments"

My controller

```
namespace Acme\testBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class testController extends Controller
{
    public function helloAction()
    {
        //return new Response('Created product id ');

        return $this->render('AcmetestBundle:test:test.html.php');
    }
}
```

My template : test.html.php

```
<?php var_dump("Hello world");?>
```

My output :

```
<!--?php var_dump("Hello world");?-->
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Probably just need to add php as a template engine to your config file.

```
templating: { engines: ['twig','php'] }
```

Comment: Yes. Here's the link to the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you google for this?

First result for "Symfony2 PHP template":
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/PHP.html

Answer (score 0):

any more suggestions? Enabled twig as Cerad suggested, cleared cache. Still keep getting

`<!--?php var_dump("Hello world");?-->`